# Deleting entity. GET or POST?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to delete an entity, should I do it in a GET or POST?

I think both are correct, but which one is better?

Comment: Neither, use a DELETE request as @dragonx suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a POST since you are changing data. DELETE, although it exists, is much less common.

Comment: thanks!
suppose a user is already logged and he make a POST, should I recheck -on server side-  if this user is logged?
I make this question cause I am thinking about someone can create a false POST. Is that possible?

Comment: In general, yes, POST should always verify that the request comes from a source that has access to the data it is changing.

Comment: It is a good practice to redirect after deleting to a GET so if you refresh you don't get the re-submission.

Comment: Thanks to both!. 
If I redirect to a GET after deleting then is not necesary to re-check that has access to the data it is changing?
or just it is a good practice?

Comment: POST is for creating entities. *you are changing data.* that normally happens with a PUT or PATCH. Deleting an entitiy should be done with a -- that's right -- DELETE request, regardless of how common or uncommon it is

Answer (score 4):

While GET and POST are the most popular HTTP methods, there's also other method, such as the DELETE method which would be appropriate.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html